# How to hide APIs of static library included by another one?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries, encapsulation

My question is that I want to develop a set of APIs that I want to expose. Let it be "SetA".

I use some APIs of third-party static library, like a mathematical solver. Let it be "SetB". In brief, SetA uses SetB's APIs.

Because I use "SetB", I have to include its header and static library file. Compiled with "SetB" library included, "SetA" library contains the "SetB" definition.

However, I don't want users to link the definition of "SetB" because of version or multiple definition issue. I don't want "SetA"'s users have to handle the issue, so is it possible to hide the definition I link statically?

Comment: For your `SetA` library, you can just provide the functions needed for the user, and don't have to expose `SetB`'s functions, right?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the visibility attributes supported by your toolchain. If you are using clang or gcc, you can hide a symbol using [`__attribute__((visibility ("hidden"))))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). Another option recommended [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) is to prefer making the default symbol visibility hidden(`-fvisibility=hidden` in gcc) and selectively expose only the symbols that should be part of your API using `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` in the declaration of the symbol.

Also, to exclude symbols from static libraries that you are linking to, you could use the linker option [`--exclude-libs lib1,lib2,...`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) or `--exclude-libs ALL` to specify all static libraries.

Comment: I did survey on this symbol before, but i thought the attribute setting works only for dynamic link library? Does it also work if "SetA" is exposed as a static library?

Comment: Added `--exclude-libs`. This would exclude the non-exported symbols from static libs that you are linking to. However, I am not sure if this would affect symbol visibility in the archive you are creating. You could always use `objcopy --localize-hidden` on the static library you create. But not sure if there's a cleaner way. Will update the answer after experimenting.